# Calling other super method directly when coming from sub

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance, coffeescript

With

```
upperclass = class Superclass
  constructor: () ->

  @somemethod: () ->
    console.log "I'm in super"

  @someothermethod: () ->
    console.log "I'm trying to reach super without going through sub!"
    @somemethod()

lowerclass = class Subclass extends Superclass
  constructor: () ->

  @somemethod: () ->
    console.log "I'm in sub but only want to go to super! I.e. not through sub, calling super here!"

  @someothermethod: () ->
    super

lowerclass.someothermethod()
```

I'd like the @somemethod call to go directly to the super method, avoiding the sub method. Is that possible? Added @ to some method declarations to make it work with the CoffeeScript tester [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:upperclass%20%3D%20class%20Superclass%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20()%20-%3E%0A%0A%20%20%40somemethod%3A%20()%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20%22I'm%20in%20super%22%0A%0A%20%20%40someothermethod%3A%20()%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20%22I'm%20trying%20to%20reach%20super%20without%20going%20through%20sub!%22%0A%20%20%20%20%40somemethod()%0A%0Alowerclass%20%3D%20class%20Subclass%20extends%20Superclass%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20()%20-%3E%0A%0A%20%20%40somemethod%3A%20()%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20%22I'm%20in%20sub%20but%20only%20want%20to%20go%20to%20super!%20I.e.%20not%20through%20sub%2C%20calling%20super%20here!%22%0A%0A%20%20%40someothermethod%3A%20()%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20super%0A%0Alowerclass.someothermethod()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a direct reference to `Superclass.somemethod`:

```
Superclass.somemethod.call @
```

I don’t think it’s possible (or necessary) to do it without naming `Superclass`.

Comment: Thanks! Ended up just add- and filtering optional args in the SubClass @somemethod. The methods rely a lot on the instance, so I guess maybe that's the more appropriate solution. At any rate it's great to know that it's possible to reference SuperClass.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Superclass::somemethod` though?

Comment: @Bergi: They’re class methods, I think (`@`).

Comment: @minitech: Oh, sure. I don't know whether the OP intended this or whether it's a side effect from his attempts.